# Where I can download tor expert bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

Why I can not find download link for tor expert bundle? Why [torproject.org](https://www.torproject.org/) removed it?

Comment: Go to source download on the new site. You will find the link to download expert bundle there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tor recently relaunched its [website](https://torproject.org/). Currently there are some [issues](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/29901) with the website. If you want to go to the old website, there is a copy at https://2019.www.torproject.org/.

The expert bundle is linked from the [old download page](https://2019.www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) and points to https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/.

Answer (score 8):

[New Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/) > [Download Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/) > [Download Tor Source Code](https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/) > Windows Expert Bundle

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a Tor Expert Bundle back in the old days, even after Vidalia development was scratched. As AXO mentioned, the Windows Expert Bundle only supplies the latest tor and its dynamic libraries at https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/. But you can create your own "Tor+ Pluggable Transport". Extract the Expert Bundle, copy the "PluggableTransports" folder (containing obfsproxy,exe at the moment) from your Tor Browser installation directory and paste it in your "new" Tor extracted folder. Copy also your "Data/Tor" folder to that new folder and edit your torrc like before. If you're using tor bridges, it's still here: https://bridges.torproject.org/. This is the least you could do to make one.
To customize your torrc, you can browse here for more details: https://tornull.org/
https://tornull.org/xeronet-rocket-torrc.php .
But if I will recommend, using Tor Browser Bundle is all we need unless we're planning a multiple tor connection. We can also update the tor folder, edit the torrc if we want to. TBB is user-friendly.
An alternative approach is using ProxAllium: https://github.com/DcodingTheWeb/ProxAllium